# xdg-open: no method available for opening -- Crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, python3

i have written a script in python3 that gets me some magnet links, the script works perfectly, but i want it to run periodically so i created a cron job to do it every other day.

While testing it i get the error that xdg-open: no method available for opening 'magnet....'

i have already checked that my default browser is firefox and the default app for magnet links is the qbitorrent, i am out of ideas on how to fix this

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'magnet:?x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found the solution,

i was using a bash file to start the python3 virtual environment, and run the script.

i added at the beginning of the file 2 environment variables

```
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
export DISPLAY=:0
```

that fixed the issue